# Preperation for Class exam (C) -> n-th root with self-written functions (no math.h or something)

Tags: c, math, exponentiation

the objective is easy:

find the geometrical middle of X1, X2, ... Xn (in my case n = 3)

BUT I have to write own functions and aren't able to use pow(), exp(), log2(), etc.

so I tried to calculate it with paper first, before I start coding.
I used 125 as result of (a * b * c) because I know the 3rd root of 125 is 5

I thought to use "125 e(1/n)"
But I'm really stuck at calculating this exp becouse I simply dont know how...
Google isn't really helpfull though..

This is just a task to learn for the exam...

Comment: What is the type for you X values? Integer or floating point? And in the case of integer, what do you want when there is no exact root?

Comment: I would go with the `log` method for the calculation. It is easier to implement than `n'th` root if you ask me.

Comment: I need float.
okay. but then I need to write log() on my own...
The Exam is about functions...
So I need to make my own functions... All  can use is if/else, while, for, and aritmethic operators

Comment: Look up Taylor series https://stackoverflow.com/q/7212158/1216776

Comment: Approximate with [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Comment: For `n`th roots, where `n` is an integer, you can implement [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).  This is an interative computational approach that makes successively better and better approximations to the correct answer until it is within a tolerance that you choose (which is limited in practice by the precision of the machine's floating-point representation).

Comment: @JohnBollinger well, I have this

```double newtonroot(double a) {

    double prevX = 1;
    double curX = 1;

    while(curX * curX != a) {
        prevX = curX;
        curX = 0.5 * (prevX + (a / prevX));
        if(curX == prevX) break;
    }

    return curX;
}```

But this only works with squareroot.... how do i implement nth?

Comment: @AwesomeSounds, you're the student.  I linked you to a good description of the method, and you have an example to consider for the square root case.  It is to your advantage to write your own implementation for the cube root.  If necessary, do the same for the fourth root.  If you want a generic function that computes any (integer) nth root then you should have a pretty good idea by then of how to generalize to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newton method to compute nth root of x.

[Newton method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) is

> y = y - f(y) / f'(y)

with

> f(y) = y^n - x

This gives the following iteration:

> y = (n - 1) * y / n + x / n * y^(1-n)

For an initial y greater than x this sequence is convergent (see [nth-root-iteration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416143/convergence-of-nth-root-iteration) )

In plain C this gives:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double nthpower(int n, double x)
{
  if (n < 0)
    return nthpower(-n, 1 / x);

  double y = 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    y = y * x;
  }

  return y;
}

int close_to_zero(double x)
{
  const double eps = 1e-10;

  return (-eps < x) && (x < eps);
}

double nthroot(int n, double x)
{
  assert(x >= 0);
  assert(n >= 0);

  switch (n)
  {
    case 0:
      return 1;

    case 1:
      return x;

    default:
      double yp, y = x;

      do
      {
        yp = y;
        y = (n - 1) * y / n + x / n * nthpower(1 - n, y);
      } while (!close_to_zero(yp - y));

      return y;
  }
}

double geometric_mean(double* x, int n)
{
  double p = 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    p *= x[i];
  }

  return nthroot(n, p);
}

int main(void)
{
  double x[6] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

  printf("GM %f\n", geometric_mean(x, 0));
  printf("GM %f\n", geometric_mean(x, 1));
  printf("GM %f\n", geometric_mean(x, 6));

  return 0;
}
```

which prints:

> GM 1.000000

> GM 2.000000

> GM 4.140681

There is room for improvement, by example, nth power can be computed more effectively by computing x.x, then x^2.x^2, then x^4.x^4... But I think that the main idea (using the Newton method) is correctly illustrated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general algorithm to find the n-th root of a number. But as we have a computer at hands we can use numerical approximations.

We have two generic methods to find the root of a monotonic function

- dichotomy: if you have one value below and one beyond, take the average and proceed. This is a very robust method but its convergence is slow
- Newton: You use the derivative formula to find a better value from an initial guess. This one is very fast, provided you start *close enough* to the root, but can be poor if you start with a bad guess. BTW we all know that the derivate for x -> x^n in x -> n * x^(n - 1)...

So a rule of thumb is to start with a dichotomy to find an acceptable guess and then go with Newton to find a very precise approximation

As we get a number of value we want to take the geometric mean, we know that the result is greater than the minimal value and less than the maximal one, so we have what we need to initialize a dichotomy.

A possible code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

// a trivial implementation for x -> x^n
double ipow(double x, int n) {
    double val = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) val *= x;
    return val;
}

int main() {
    //double *arr;
    int i, n;
    printf("Enter the number of values: ");
    for (;;) {
        if (1 == scanf("%d", &n) && n > 1) break;
        printf("Invalid input, try again\n");
        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n');
        if (c == EOF) return 1;
    }
    double min = DBL_MAX, max = -DBL_MAX, a = 1;
    //arr = malloc(n * sizeof(*arr));
    printf("Enter %d values: ", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double val;
        for (;;) {
            if (1 == scanf("%lg", &val) && (val > 0)) break;
            printf("Invalid input, try again\n");
            int c;
            while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n');
            if (c == EOF) return 1;
        }
        a *= val;
        if (min > val) min = val;
        if (max < val) max = val;
    }
    // we want x, ipow(x, n) "close" to a, we know min <= x <= max
    // first a dichotomy
    double x, eps = 1 / 10.;
    int nd = 0, nn = 0; // will trace the number of dich and Newton iterations
    for (;;) {
        ++nd;
        x = (min + max) / 2;
        if (max - min < x * eps) {
            break;
        }
        if (ipow(x, n) < a) min = x;
        else max = x;
    }
    eps = 1e-10;
    // let's go with Newton
    for (;;) {
        ++nn;
        double x1 = x;
        x = x1 + (a - ipow(x1, n)) / n / ipow(x1, n - 1);
        if (x1 - x > -eps * x && x1 - x < eps * x) break;
    }
    printf("sqrt%d(%g) = %g (%d dichotomy, %d Newton)\n", n, a, x, nd, nn);
    return 0;
}
```

It is probably not the most efficient way, but it is robust because it is able to compute the geometric mean of 1e-300 and 1e300 while 1e300 * 1e300 overflows to  inf... (but as fortunately inf is greater that any float value, the dichotomy part works fine)

Answer (score 0):

Just like "abelenky" wrote in his (deleted) answer, you may also use a binary search if you want to calculate the inverse function of a strictly increasing function and you know that the result is positive:

Searching the `n`-th root of a number `y` is the inverse function of the function `y=f(x, n)`; for `x>0`, this function is strictly increasing.

Because writing the C code is for your homework practice, I will not show working C code here but only explain you the principle:

Before doing the binary search, you have to perform two checks:

- If the number is zero, the solution (the root) is also zero.
- If the number is negative, you may calculate `-root(-y, n)` if `n` is odd; if `n` is even, there is no solution.
  (`-root(-y, n)` means: You calculate the `n`-th root of the absolute value of `y` and change the sign of the result.)

Now search the starting number `g`:

```
double g = 1;
while(f(g) > y) { g /= 2; }
while(f(g) < y) { g *= 2; }
```

In the case of the `n`-th root, `f(x)` is `pow(x, n)`, which you can easily replace by a self-written function (using a `for` loop) if `n` is known to be a positive integer.

Then perform the binary search:

```
double x;
int i;
for(i=0; i<60; i++)
{
    if(f(x+g) <= y) { x+=g; }
    g /= 2;
}
```

Due to the precision of `double` variables, increasing the number of loop runs will not change the result. If you are using more precise data types (such as `long double`), you need more loop runs to get the best result possible.